# Long running transactions with EF and SQL Server using Read Commited

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

I'm using EF6.1 and SQL Server on a WPF thick-client application and by default I'm opening a transaction with each DbContext I instantiate (I commit it and reopen it on every `SaveChanges()` unless specified otherwise). The isolation level for these transactions is READ COMMITED (`IsolationLevel.ReadCommited`).

I'm by default opening a new context (thus a new transaction) on each "main view". The application is kind of a fake-MDI app and each MDI View will use its own `DbContext`... "main views" (every MDI tab/window) can contain other secondary views (think of small modal windows for specific data entry and things like that) which will share the same context (and transaction) as the opened in the main view. I'm using a structure like `UseCase -> Views -> ViewModels`... generally a "UseCase" will open up a `DbContext` and can spawn multiple views, which will share it. Those secondary views usually call `SaveChanges()` without committing the transaction, that's why I want to have them in first place.

I've done some performance tests with a single user on a lab server and there doesn't seem to exist any difference (performance-wise) either opening the transaction when instancing the context, or not having transactions at all (other than the one EF opens by default on `SaveChanges()`).

I'm no SQL Server expert, so I'm wondering if there are any implications (when the app is used by multiple users on a production server) on having many long-running transactions opened on SQL Server with that isolation level (I understand the implications on other isolation levels which may lock reads, but it's not the case). I'm handling concurrency errors manually when committing the transactions.

Am I doing the right thing here, should I stick to short-living transactions, or is it just a matter of preference?

I've been trying to find an answer to this but haven't found anything definitive (there's some people that says long-living transactions are not a good idea, but they don't seem to explain why).

Comment: A transaction should be open for as short as possible because of locking and the amount of work todo in a rollback case. How long is a transaction running?

Comment: Why would secondary views have to call `SaveChanges`? It seems to me that the context that's shared among views collects all changes, so you can do one `SaveChanges` call at the moment where you're now committing the transaction.

Comment: @GertArnold , well, those secondary views receive a context (which might be a new through DI, or passed in), so they make the changes to the entities they are editing and call SaveChanges when done. This process might be part of a bigger change (which may need rolling back if the user cancels on the main view) or might be an isolated edition on a complete new context... the view is not aware of that, it just calls SaveChanges when it's done with its editing. I could pass a parameter to the view saying if it should save changes or not, but I find transactions more elegant and spot on.

Comment: OK, I understand. But I wouldn't say that transaction management in persistent-ignorant application code is more elegant than collecting changes in a unit of work (which could be a context) that encapsulates a db transaction. I'd rather look for ways to share a unit of work between views that are involved in one use case. Some IoC containers can bind the lifecycle of components to that of an aggregate root in an object graph (i.e. main view + sub views).

Comment: I was of course oversimplifying, I'm passing what I call a "ServiceTransaction" which has a UoC (my dbcontext is the UoC actually) in it and I use Services for accessing. I might just track my changes or pass the entities around (instead of the context), but I felt **conceptually** transactions were just what I needed... till this precise subject came into my mind and I questioned if it was the right thing to do.

Comment: Err, I meant UoW... don't know where that UoC came from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there's some people that says long-living transactions are not a good
>   idea, but they don't seem to explain why

Just a couple of reasons:

MS SQL transaction, depending on its isolation level, could obtain record (more general) or even metadata (more exotic) locks. The more time transaction lives, the more locks it could obtain, hence, the probability of deadlocks increases.

Also, uncommitted transaction means server resource utilization. Transaction log will grow and its data for active transactions could not be truncated, server must remember all of things, which has been done within transaction to commit them or rollback.

> by default I'm opening a transaction with each DbContext I instantiate

There should be a reason to do this. The only reason I can imagine, is non-EF changes to a database, which must be consistent with EF changes. Otherwise, you're doing an extra-job, which at least useless, and could waste resources of database server.

Comment: Does it get locks using Read Commited isolation? Also, why would a long lived transaction use more resources *just* because they are longer lived than others? I'm genuinely asking these questions because it does not make sense in my head (and as I said, I'm not a db expert)

Comment: The reason to use transactions, as I explained, is being able to call SaveChanges on secondary views (so those views are self managed), while not persisting changes to database till Commit is called on the "main" view

Comment: @Jcl: SQL server gets *write* locks using `ReadCommitted` (I'd recommend to read this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). Long lived transactions use more resources, because, *usually*, the more transaction live, the more operations are being performed within transaction. About your approach in whole, I agree with  Gert Arnold's comment.

Comment: that seems to be a great link which I had missed... I'll read it and try to understand it better. Thank you, I'm marking your answer as accepted since it seems to be spot on.